# defining lists with .append in python

Tags: python, list, loops, append, typeerror

```
height, width, device = 99, 99, 99
num_pieces = 3

#create datastructure to hold piece dimensions*

pieces = [[height, width, device]]

for i in range(num_pieces - 1):
    pieces = pieces.append([0,0,0])
    print "initial list"
    print pieces

#get dimentions for the rest of the list starting at second element*

for i in pieces[1: ]:
    print "list in loop"
    print pieces
# get height of the ith piece
    print "please enter the height of piece %d" % (pieces.index(i)+1)
    height = float(raw_input(">>"))
# get width of the ith piece
    print "please enter the width of piece %d" % (pieces.index(i)+1)
    width = float(raw_input(">>"))
# get device of the ith piece
    print "please enter the hanging device of piece %d" % (pieces.index(i)+1)
    device = float(raw_input(">>"))

# test if element is empty
if i == [0,0,0]:
    i = [height, width, device]

#view completeled list of dimensions
print pieces
```

I think there is something wrong with my `.append` (I shouldn't be using `.extend` should I?)

This is **my error**. I know something is wrong with the `[1: ]` as well but first I want to figure out **how to fix the .append problem**.

```
File "l_long.py", line 36, in <module>
    for i in pieces[1: ]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code, and then we can focus on the various other problems. Also, it would be good if you gave us some typical output that you expect this code to print.

Comment: why u using this??? `pieces.index(i)+1` you can use directly `pieces[0][i]`

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because of this line:

```
pieces = pieces.append([0,0,0])
```

Which sets the value of `pieces` to `None` because the list `append()` method effectively returns that value. Most container methods that change the associated container object in-place don't return anything (which Python makes appear as though they had returned the value `None`).

In your code this means that `pieces` gets its value changed to this after the first iteration of:

```
for i in range(num_pieces - 1)
```

…hence the `TypeError` you're seeing occurs.

Change the line to simply:

```
pieces.append([0,0,0])
```

And that error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but there is some flaw in your code:

```
pieces = [[height, width, device]]   
# Here 'height', 'width', and 'device' must be defined, else you will get NameError.

num_pieces # Must defined. It may be the length of the list??

pieces = pieces.append([0,0,0]) # This is going to override your list
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some errors in your code i have corrected them with comments at each correction. Check this one i think this solves your problem :-

```
height=0   
width=0
device=0
num_pieces=10

# you need to provide initialisation with above fields in your program which is required

pieces = [[height, width, device]]


for i in range(num_pieces - 1):
    '''in your code line below returns null and when pieces become
       null it has no attribute append '''
      # pieces=pieces.append([0,0,0])   
    pieces.append([0,0,0])

#print pieces

j=0

for i in pieces[:]:
   # get height of the ith piece
   #print "please enter the height of piece %d" 
   #height = float(raw_input(">>"))

   '''you can have user provided values
      i have hard coded the values for
      height width and device for the
      time being for simplicity '''

   height=10                                    
   # get width of the ith piece
   #print "please enter the width of piece %d" 
   #width = float(raw_input(">>"))

   width=10
   # get device of the ith piece
   # print "please enter the hanging device of piece %d"
   #device = float(raw_input(">>"))

   device=100

   # test if element is empty
   if i == [0,0,0]:
      i = [height, width, device]

   if j <= len(pieces):
      # in your code no need for (pieces.index(i)+1)
      pieces[j]=i
      j=j+1

##view completeled list of dimensions
print pieces
```

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to coding and this is my first semi difficult problem. Your answer helped SO much!